# how open file system's GUI-window through terminal

Tags: shell, command

is there any shell command that open file system's GUI-window of the terminal's current working directory?

Comment: That would depend on which file manager you're using, and possibly what window manager / desktop manager you've got.

Comment: @roaima thanks, i google about it and it seems if i know my file manager i can handle the case. of course i found out that the command "xdg-open ." works for all file managers, now can you please tell me how i can figure out what file manager i'm using? (actually i find it by trying different file manager names, and its nautilus, but i want the command that give me this)

Answer (score 2):

Just type:

```
/usr/bin/gnome-open .
```

Note the spce-dot at the end, where the dot represents the current directory. I actually created a symlink called `run`, so I can easily open anything from the command line (folders, random files, etc.).

**Update**:

On newer versions of Gnome, this seems to have been replaced by `xdg-open`. In fact, `libgnome2-bin`, the package needed to install `gnome-open`, is not available for Ubuntu 19.10. Here is the new version:

```
/usr/bin/xdg-open .
```

Comment: thanks a lot, just exploring /usr/bin/gnome- was so informitive per se! i didn't know about that. but there was no gnome-open in there. it's worth mentioning i use ubuntu 16.04

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04, it is definitely `/usr/bin/gnome-open` but perhaps it is in another directory on 16.04. Try `gnome-open` without the full path.